# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException(Date_Format)

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am using Sql-Server 2012 and have a query

```
string sqlQuery = "SELECT distinct DATE_FORMAT(collectiondate,'%m/%d/%Y') FROM reports  where patientid= " + patientId + " and isdeleted=false order by collectiondate desc";
            var lst = Session.CreateSQLQuery(sqlQuery).List();
            ArrayList rpt = new ArrayList();
            rpt.Add("--ALL--");
```

but I am getting an error

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'DATE_FORMAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.
```

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should rather try using [CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),1)
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/13398)

That being said, I would recomend returning the values as is from the Database, and leaving the formatting to the UI.

Answer (score 2):

There's no `DATE_FORMAT` function in SQL Server.

You need to use [`CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) function

```
SELECT distinct SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), collectiondate, 1) ...
```

Also, formatting is best to be done in the code, not in SQL Server. You should return your date as `DATE` or `DATETIME` column and format it in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the FORMAT() command in SQL Server 2012 instead.

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME = GETDATE();
SELECT  FORMAT(@d, 'mm/dd/yy', 'en-US') AS 'Result';
```